# Mongodb moongose log table

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, logging, database-design

I am interested in how to create log table that writes data in own table, every time user makes some request.
And how to get data like this:

```
{
            _id: ObjectId('4f442120eb03305789000000'),
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            logname: null,
            user: 'frank',
            time: ISODate("2000-10-10T20:55:36Z"),
            path: "/apache_pb.gif",
            request: "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0",
            status: 200,
            response_size: 2326,
            referrer: "[http://www.example.com/start.html](http://www.example.com/start.html)",
            user_agent: "Mozilla/4.08 [en] (Win98; I ;Nav)"
            }
```

Maybe not all of this data, but atleast who made the request, what type of request, path and time.
I am using nodejs, mongodb, mongoose.

Comment: All of the request information is inside request header. I will suggest you ti create a object with required filed and then insert into mongo database. You dont have to use any 3rd party package.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `middleware` that logs all the requests, being sent to your server, to the MongoDB Database.

You can easily get the information you are looking for, using these npm packages,

1 - [useragent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/useragent)

2 - [express-useragent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-useragent)

Answer (score 0):

I solved on this way.

My middlewere

```
const Log = require("../models/log");

const log = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

    let user_id = req.user.id
    let firstName = req.user.firstName
    let method = req.method
    let path = req.path    

    const log = new Log({ user_id, firstName, method, path });

    try {
        await log.save()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }

      next();
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(401).send(e);
    }
  };

module.exports = log;
```

Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const logSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: String,
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
    },
    method: {
        type: String,
    },
    path: {
        type: String,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
})

const Log = mongoose.model('Log', logSchema);

module.exports = Log;
```

and router

```
const express = require('express')
const Log = require('../models/log')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
const router = new express.Router()

//Create log
router.post('/logs', async (req, res) => {
    const log = new Log({
        ...req.body
    })

    try {
        await log.save()
        res.status(201).send(log)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})

//Sort and search
router.get('/logs', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const match = {}
    const sort = {}

    if (req.query.completed) {
        match.completed = req.query.completed === 'true'
    }

    if (req.query.sortBy) {
        const parts = req.query.sortBy.split(':')
        sort[parts[0]] = parts[1] === 'desc' ? -1 : 1
    }

    try {
        await req.user.populate({
            path: 'logs',
            match,
            options: {
                limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
                skip: parseInt(req.query.skip),
                sort
            }
        }).execPopulate()
        res.send(req.user.logs)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send()
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```